# Regular Expressions: Identify physical quantities i.e.numbers followed by it's SI/Imperial units in a string

Tags: python, regex

*I am trying to write a regex pattern to identify physical quantities in a string i.e.numbers followed by it's SI/Imperial units.*

The pattern in which they occur in a string could vary a lot.

Some examples:

```
'510 PS (375 kW / 503 bhp) at 8500 rpm' , 
'100 Litre (26.4 Gallon US / 22 Gallon Imperial)', 
'(bore) 82mm x 62mm (stroke)-> ~3929cm³',
'115 bhp / 86 kW\n\t\t\t @ 6,000 rpm','442lb ft @ 3000-7500rpm',
'356 Nm (36.3 mkg / 263 lb-ft) at 5000 rpm (~ 2.3)'
```

etcetra and you can now imagine other such weird patterns.

The main aim here is to always capture a number followed by its unit
example: '510 PS','3000-7500rpm', '26.4 Gallon US','86 kW','263 lb-ft', etcetra.

So far i tried a bunch of stuff:

```
re.findall(r"\d+\.*?\d+?\s?\W?\s?[a-zA-Z\s+]+",string),
re.findall(r"\d+\.+\d+?\s*\W*\s*[a-zA-Z\s+]*",string), 
re.findall('\d+\.?\d*?\s?\w+\W?\w+',string),
```

But most probably this regex cant be written for all possible edge cases at once so maybe try a bunch of regex and then run them all on a string and get the matches combined in a list for further processing.

Any help is much appreciated. Point me in the right direction. Thanks a ton!

EDIT:

```
tests = ['209.5 in | 5320 mm.','4,868 mm (191.65 in)','64.5inches','front 15.6x1.4 in/rear 13.7x1.3 in',
 '27.7 US gal (23.1 UK/gal)','90 Litre (23.8 Gallon US / 19.8 Gallon Imperial)','n.b.'," ",
 '103.1 inches - Track : Front 65.7 inches / Rear 63.8 inches','95 mm x 76.4 mm (3.74 x 3.01 in)',
 '510 PS (375 kW / 503 bhp) at 8500 rpm' , '100 Litre (26.4 Gallon US / 22 Gallon Imperial)', 
'(bore) 82mm x 62mm (stroke)-> ~3929cm³','115 bhp / 86 kW\n\t\t\t @ 6,000 rpm','442lb ft @ 3000-7500rpm',
'356 Nm (36.3 mkg / 263 lb-ft) at 5000 rpm (~ 2.3 inch)','65.0 mm (2.6 in) / 58.8 mm (2.3 in)',
 '339 BHP (249.504 KW)  @ 7000 RPM','690 Nm (70.4 mkg / 509 lb-ft) at 5500 rpm (~ 540 PS)','500Nm','8,500 rpm',
 '11.5 : 1','16,2 :1','0-100 km/h (0-62 mph)','~331.45 kph / 206 mph','317 km/h | 197.016 mph (limited)',
 '668PS-per-tonne (659bhp)','2 kg/PS = 4.6 lbs/hp = 360 kW/T','0.21 bhp / kg','6.1 lb/CV',
 '3.91:1 2.29:1 1.58:1 1.18:1 0.94:1 0.79:1 0.67:1','245/45r17','15.6 litres/100kms (18.1 mpg)']

RESULTS:

209.5 in | 5320 mm. -> ['209.5 in ', '5320 mm']
4,868 mm (191.65 in) -> ['4,868 mm ', '191.65 in']
64.5inches -> ['64.5inches']
front 15.6x1.4 in/rear 13.7x1.3 in -> ['15.6x1', '4 in', '13.7x1', '3 in']
27.7 US gal (23.1 UK/gal) -> ['27.7 US gal ', '23.1 UK']
90 Litre (23.8 Gallon US / 19.8 Gallon Imperial) -> ['90 Litre ', '23.8 Gallon US ', '19.8 Gallon Imperial']
n.b. -> []
  -> []
103.1 inches - Track : Front 65.7 inches / Rear 63.8 inches -> ['103.1 inches ', '65.7 inches ', '63.8 inches']
95 mm x 76.4 mm (3.74 x 3.01 in) -> ['95 mm x 76', '4 mm ', '3.74 x 3', '01 in']
510 PS (375 kW / 503 bhp) at 8500 rpm -> ['510 PS ', '375 kW ', '503 bhp', '8500 rpm']
100 Litre (26.4 Gallon US / 22 Gallon Imperial) -> ['100 Litre ', '26.4 Gallon US ', '22 Gallon Imperial']
(bore) 82mm x 62mm (stroke)-> ~3929cm³ -> ['82mm x 62mm ', '3929cm³']
115 bhp / 86 kW
             @ 6,000 rpm -> ['115 bhp ', '86 kW\n\t\t\t ', '6,000 rpm']
442lb ft @ 3000-7500rpm -> ['442lb ft ', '3000', '7500rpm']
356 Nm (36.3 mkg / 263 lb-ft) at 5000 rpm (~ 2.3 inch) -> ['356 Nm ', '36.3 mkg ', '263 lb', '5000 rpm ', '2.3 inch']
65.0 mm (2.6 in) / 58.8 mm (2.3 in) -> ['65.0 mm ', '2.6 in', '58.8 mm ', '2.3 in']
339 BHP (249.504 KW)  @ 7000 RPM -> ['339 BHP ', '249.504 KW', '7000 RPM']
690 Nm (70.4 mkg / 509 lb-ft) at 5500 rpm (~ 540 PS) -> ['690 Nm ', '70.4 mkg ', '509 lb', '5500 rpm ', '540 PS']
500Nm -> ['500Nm']
8,500 rpm -> ['8,500 rpm']
11.5 : 1 -> ['11.5 ', '1']
16,2 :1 -> ['16,2 ', '1']
0-100 km/h (0-62 mph) -> ['0', '100 km', '0', '62 mph']
~331.45 kph / 206 mph -> ['331.45 kph ', '206 mph']
317 km/h | 197.016 mph (limited) -> ['317 km', '197.016 mph ']
668PS-per-tonne (659bhp) -> ['668PS', '659bhp']
2 kg/PS = 4.6 lbs/hp = 360 kW/T -> ['2 kg', '4.6 lbs', '360 kW']
0.21 bhp / kg -> ['0.21 bhp ']
6.1 lb/CV -> ['6.1 lb']
3.91:1 2.29:1 1.58:1 1.18:1 0.94:1 0.79:1 0.67:1 -> ['3.91', '1 2', '29', '1 1', '58', '1 1', '18', '1 0', '94', '1 0', '79', '1 0', '67', '1']
245/45r17 -> ['245', '45r17']
15.6 litres/100kms (18.1 mpg) -> ['15.6 litres', '100kms ', '18.1 mpg']
```

This is sample tests that hopefully the regex pattern should be able to detect. I tried @Daweo approach and it failing some of the tests.
Can you please suggest any improvements to pass those tests too. Thanks a ton!

EDIT part 2:

This is a huge list of testcases if the regex passes all of this then my job will be done. you can find it [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Qw5rMzDf5ytN3iW8Fm3LaZNPV-htNWVvkqfIMR59DEI/edit?usp=sharing)

After all the help from you folks and some digging of my own:
I have used this function to get most of my job done. If anyone can point out anything that I can improve in this pattern to improve accuracy it would make a world of difference.

```
def cleanup(s):
    pattern = re.compile(r"\d+(?:[.,-x]{0,}\d*?\s?[a-zA-Z°µ ][a-zA-Z0-9°µ/*^-]*)",re.I)
    return(re.findall(pattern,s))
    #return(bool(pattern.match(s)))
```

Please help me improve the above function to pass all the [testcases found here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Qw5rMzDf5ytN3iW8Fm3LaZNPV-htNWVvkqfIMR59DEI/edit)

Thanks a ton everyone of you!

Comment: If *example: '510 PS','3000-7500rpm', '26.4 Gallon US','86 kW','263 lb-ft', etcetra.* then `3000-7500` must be number by your defintion, whilst I would except `7500` as number here. What definition of number are you using?

Comment: You can try `([\d,.]+)\s?([\w\d-]+)`

Comment: 3000-7500 is of course a range of numbers. Ideally i would want to include it too but for now I will ignore that example and write a separate regex to counter this problem.

Comment: Are those expected results that you added in your edit? Cause I see a lot of quantities without units there...

Comment: No they are the results after trying the method suggested by @Daweo below. The final aim is still to identify numbers with it's units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you get a lot of false positives with your current method since it recognizes any string (excluding punctuation) as a potential unit.
One way to go around this would be to include all possible units beforehand. This doesn't seem easy since a given unit can be expressed in different ways like:

```
US gal; UK/gal; Gallon US; Gallon Imperial
```

But if you can list all the possible unusual units it should be doable:

For the classic SI and imperial units you can import `PhysicalQuantities`:

```
import PhysicalQuantities
from PhysicalQuantities import imperial
u, _ = PhysicalQuantities.units_list()
```

This gives you `u`:

```
['A', 'Bit', 'Btu', 'C', 'F', 'H', 'Hz', 'J', 'K', 'N', 'Ohm', 'Pa', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'Wb', 'acres', 'arcmin', 'arcsec', 'barn', 'cd', 'cup', 'currency', 'deg', 'degF', 'floz', 'ft', 'furlong', 'g', 'galUK', 'galUS', 'h', 'hp', 'inch', 'kg', 'lb', 'lm', 'lx', 'm', 'mi', 'mil', 'min', 'mol', 'nmi', 'oz', 'psi', 'pt', 'qt', 'rad', 's', 'sr', 'tbsp', 'ton', 'tsp', 'yd']
```

You can then add the unusual ones manually and combine units:

```
import re

data = """'209.5 in | 5320 mm.','4,868 mm (191.65 in)','64.5inches','front 15.6x1.4 in/rear 13.7x1.3 in',
 '27.7 US gal (23.1 UK/gal)','90 Litre (23.8 Gallon US / 19.8 Gallon Imperial)','n.b.'," ",
 '103.1 inches - Track : Front 65.7 inches / Rear 63.8 inches','95 mm x 76.4 mm (3.74 x 3.01 in)',
 '510 PS (375 kW / 503 bhp) at 8500 rpm' , '100 Litre (26.4 Gallon US / 22 Gallon Imperial)', 
'(bore) 82mm x 62mm (stroke)-> ~3929cm³','115 bhp / 86 kW\n\t\t\t @ 6,000 rpm','442lb ft @ 3000-7500rpm',
'356 Nm (36.3 mkg / 263 lb-ft) at 5000 rpm (~ 2.3 inch)','65.0 mm (2.6 in) / 58.8 mm (2.3 in)',
 '339 BHP (249.504 KW)  @ 7000 RPM','690 Nm (70.4 mkg / 509 lb-ft) at 5500 rpm (~ 540 PS)','500Nm','8,500 rpm',
 '11.5 : 1','16,2 :1','0-100 km/h (0-62 mph)','~331.45 kph / 206 mph','317 km/h | 197.016 mph (limited)',
 '668PS-per-tonne (659bhp)','2 kg/PS = 4.6 lbs/hp = 360 kW/T','0.21 bhp / kg','6.1 lb/CV',
 '3.91:1 2.29:1 1.58:1 1.18:1 0.94:1 0.79:1 0.67:1','245/45r17','15.6 litres/100kms (18.1 mpg)'"""

prefix_pattern = r'(?:p|n|u|μ|m|c|d|h|k|M|G|T|E)'
unit_pattern = rf'(?:{"|".join(u)}|PS|l|rpm|Gal(?:lon)?|US|UK|Imperial|in(?:ches)?|kilo|bhp|lbs|lit(?:re|er)s?|per|ton(?:ne)?s?|cu)'
exponent_pattern = r'(?:²|³)'

phys_pattern = re.compile(rf'\d+[ .,-]?\d*(?:[ *./p-]*{prefix_pattern}?{unit_pattern}{exponent_pattern}?)+(?![a-zA-Z])', re.IGNORECASE)

print(re.findall(phys_pattern, data))
```

The key part is to combine your units in the form `[ *./p-]*{prefix_pattern}?{unit_pattern}{exponent_pattern}?` so that your expression can match for example `MBit/s` as well as `km / s²`.

Output:

```
['209.5 in', '5320 mm', '4,868 mm', '191.65 in', '64.5inches', '1.4 in', '1.3 in', '27.7 US gal', '23.1 UK/gal', '23.8 Gallon US', '19.8 Gallon Imperial', '103.1 inches', '65.7 inches', '63.8 inches', '95 mm', '76.4 mm', '3.01 in', '510 PS', '375 kW', '503 bhp', '8500 rpm', '26.4 Gallon US', '22 Gallon Imperial', '82mm', '62mm', '3929cm³', '115 bhp', '86 kW', '6,000 rpm', '442lb ft', '3000-7500rpm', '356 Nm', '36.3 mkg', '263 lb-ft', '5000 rpm', '2.3 inch', '65.0 mm', '2.6 in', '58.8 mm', '2.3 in', '339 BHP', '249.504 KW', '7000 RPM', '690 Nm', '70.4 mkg', '509 lb-ft', '5500 rpm', 
'540 PS', '500Nm', '8,500 rpm', '0-100 km/h', '0-62 mph', '331.45 kph', '206 mph', '317 km/h', '197.016 mph', '668PS-per-tonne', '659bhp', '2 kg/PS', '4.6 lbs/hp', '360 kW/T', '0.21 bhp / kg', '6.1 lb/CV', '15.6 litres', '100kms', '18.1 mpg']
```

I think all of your inputs are matched in this case but you might want to tinker with the expressions a bit depending on the units you could get.

Note/Edit: the use of the flag `re.IGNORECASE` makes some prefixes redundant (`m` vs `M`) and can lead to false positives. However it avoids some false negatives since your input seems to vary a lot (`rpm` or `RPM`...)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please explain the use of quantifier_pattern = r'(?:p|n|u|μ|m|c|d|h|k|M|G|T|E)' in your code. I only understand quantifiers like +,?,* etc

Comment: re.findall(r""\d+[.,-x]{0,}\d*?\s?(\w+\W\w*[.,-x]{0,}\s?\w+)"gmi",string)   This is something I have been working on and it works well except for a few cases

Comment: well it has nothing todo with regex quantifiers. I admit it is kind of confusing. Maybe I should have named it [prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_prefix)? editing my answer right away...

Comment: so if i include units like km/h, kmph, lb-ft, etc. and all other units that i want to capture then this will work eventually. Will it be able to handle spaces, hyphens, other characters in between the units?

Comment: you don't need to include `km/h`, `kmph` and `lb-ft` specifically since you already have `k` (as prefix) `m`, `h`, `lb` and `ft` (as units) and `p`, `-` and `/` (as separators, see `[ *./p-]*`) in the regex. So the number of units you have to add shouldn't be that high

Comment: Thanks a ton! I will use your function and my function as a two pronged approach. Please suggest any improvements in my function that you deem necessary and help me pass almost all the testcases if possible. You can find the function and extra testcases in latest edit.

Comment: The pattern `"\d+[.,-x]{0,}\d*?\s?(\w+\W\w*[.,-x]{0,}\s?\w+)"` triggers a lot of false positives and breaks the result in most cases. One advantage of my solution is that all outputs have the right format. The drawback is that some are missed: in your latest example, `cu` was not included... I've added it but some others might still be missing...

Comment: It seems that there isn't always a white space between physical quantites. I therefore changed the lookahead from `(?!\w)` to `(?![a-zA-Z])`. Do you know how many results are supposed to be found in your example (the long one)? My answer finds 14667 and they all seem to be correctly formatted (it gets things like 0.92 bhp/cu in)

Comment: Adding support for the liter/litre/l and `kilo` brings it to 15322. Still some false positive might occur. eg: `PJJ`

Comment: your answers works extremely well. Just to clarify (bc I'm not much knowledgeable in advanced regex stuff) your regex can automatically identify complex units like ``` 'lb-ft', 'N-m', 'km/h' ``` etc. units that are made up of other units and are separated by delimiter. But units like ``` 'Nm', 'kgm', 'psi','kPa'``` wont work since it is complex but not separated by delimiter if it is not included in the list of "u". Am I correct ? Do I have the right understanding now? Thank you for all the help!

Comment: The prefix, separators and exponents are optional so `Nm` `kgm` will be recognized. `kPa` as well since `k` is the prefix pattern and `Pa` in `u`.  `psi` is in `u` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it following way

```
import string
import re
punct = re.escape(string.punctuation)
tests = ['510 PS (375 kW / 503 bhp) at 8500 rpm' , 
'100 Litre (26.4 Gallon US / 22 Gallon Imperial)', 
'(bore) 82mm x 62mm (stroke)-> ~3929cm³',
'115 bhp / 86 kW\n\t\t\t @ 6,000 rpm','442lb ft @ 3000-7500rpm',
'356 Nm (36.3 mkg / 263 lb-ft) at 5000 rpm (~ 2.3)']
for t in tests:
    print(re.findall(f'\\d+[.,]?\\d*[^{punct}]*',t))
```

output

```
['510 PS ', '375 kW ', '503 bhp', '8500 rpm']
['100 Litre ', '26.4 Gallon US ', '22 Gallon Imperial']
['82mm x 62mm ', '3929cm']
['115 bhp ', '86 kW\n\t\t\t ', '6,000 rpm']
['442lb ft ', '3000', '7500rpm']
['356 Nm ', '36.3 mkg ', '263 lb', '5000 rpm ', '2.3']
```

Explanation: I used following pattern `\\d+[.,]?\\d*` to describe number i.e. one or more digits, optionally `.` or `,` then zero or more digits, feel free to change it to pattern compliant with your definition of number. After number grab everything to first encountered punctuation character, where punctuation character is defined as one of `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~`

Note that there are trailing whitespaces in some cases, but they might be easile removed using `.rstrip()` method for example

```
found = ['115 bhp ', '86 kW\n\t\t\t ', '6,000 rpm']
cleaned = [i.rstrip() for i in found]
print(cleaned)
```

output

```
['115 bhp', '86 kW', '6,000 rpm']
```

Note that there are some false-positives (for example last element of last row), but they are easy to dectect after cleaning, as it should suffice to check if last character is digit. I am not sure why superscript 3 is missing, as it is not one of `string.punctuation`.